# ¿Las llamadas ajax pueden sobrecargar un servidor?

Tags: ajax, sobrecarga

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que tiene algunos elementos de la base de datos, por lo cual tengo que hacer llamadas ajax para cada componente, tengo cerca de 50 tablas las cuales tienen marcas, modelos, tipos de producto, etc.

Es así que para hacerlo en una SPA llamo a todas esos elementos via ajax para no tener que recargar la pagina. Solo para marcas, modelos y tipos de producto, serían 150 llamadas ajax, las llamadas las hago así:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 'tipo': 'congelador'},
  url: "<?php echo site_url();?>"+"/marca/obtenerMarcasbytipo",
  success : function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      //console.log(key+" "+val.id_marca +" "+val.nombre_marca);
      $("#marca_congelador").append('<option value="'+ val.id_marca + '">' + val.nombre_marca + '</option>');
    });

  }
});
```

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Todas estas llamadas pueden sobrecargar el servidor, y si es así, debería separar todas estas llamadas para evitarlo?**

Comment: Al igual que cualquier llamada, síncrona o asíncrona, puede y va a sobrecargar el servidor, si supera su capacidad.

Comment: Puedes crear una sola funcion que devuelva todo lo que tu quieres obtener?

Answer (score 3):

Para el servidor que atiende las peticiones, no le es 100% relevante si la llamada viene por Ajax, por Browser, por `curl` u otro. Al final del día, la llamada es un ciclo request-response que debe ser atendido. Muchas peticiones al servidor lo van a sobrecargar.

Te recomiendo que tengas los siguientes puntos a considerar en tu aplicación backend:

1. Reducir el "chattiness". Es decir, que la cantidad de ciclos request-response generados hacia el servidor sea la menor posible. Es mejor proveer la información en 1 request que proveer la misma información en 10 requests.
2. Comprimir la respuesta del servidor. De esta manera, reduces el tiempo de latencia de comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor. Puedes utilizar la cabecera `Content-Encoding: gzip`, por poner un ejemplo. Más info: [Http compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).
3. **El protocolo importa**. Si es posible, utiliza HTTP 2 en lugar de HTTP 1.x, puesto que HTTP 2 trae múltiples mejoras para la interacción con el servidor backend. Puedes ver una lista de los servidores con soporte de HTTP 2 aquí: [http2-spec Implementations](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations)

Answer (score 3):

> **¿Todas estas llamadas pueden sobrecargar el servidor?**

Sí, cualquier tipo de `request`, sea directo o por `ajax`, el servidor tiene que procesar.

> **y si es así, ¿Debería separar todas estas llamadas para evitarlo?**

Sí, y a la primera carga solamente llama a las que sean esenciales para tus casos de uso, dudo mucho que tengas que llamar a las 150 para un caso de uso.

Realiza pruebas de stress y verifica qué tanto rendimiento tienes, una buena herramienta recomendada: `Apache JMeter` http://jmeter.apache.org/

Juega con la `caché` para evitar sobre cargas al servidor a nivel de `$.ajax` y te sugiero almacenar cierta información haciendo uso de las `APIs` de `HTML5`: `localStorage`, `SessionStorage` en el lado del cliente.

**LocalStorage** está aceptado por el 92.96% de navegadores según: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

**SessionStorage** también con un 92.96% según: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage